# Is there a way to test Slash Commands in Slack without a signed cert?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial: https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands

However, it looks like, despite the documentation saying that a "non-distributed app" can send HTTP POST requests to an API, but in the menu where one defines a new slash command, under the URL, it keeps saying "use HTTPS for security" (and doesn't appear to take a self-signed cert, as is also mentioned in the documentation).

I don't want to buy a CA cert just to test this out, has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved- just put "https://" before the host address, it'll let you submit the web form to create the bot, and then you can edit it back to normal HTTP afterward.